# Scala Function returning semi-colon error

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```
def TempConversion(ciferTemp: Double, typeDeg: String): Double = {
   var celsit: Double = 0.0
   var far: Double = 0.0

   if (typeDeg = "c")

   far = (ciferTemp - 32) / (5.0 / 9.0)
   println(far + "en farhenheit")

   else if (typeDeg ="f") {
   celsit = (ciferTemp * (5.0 / 9.0)) + 32
   println(celsit + "en celsius")}

}
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with this function, it tells me a semi-colon is expected.

Comment: For one thing in your if statements you need to do a boolean comparator "==".  Currently you are making an assignment to the value typeDeg.  Also you need to put some code blocks {} around the conditional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making some changes

```
def TempConversion(ciferTemp: Double, typeDeg: String): Double = {
    if (typeDeg == "c") {
      val far = (ciferTemp - 32) / (5.0 / 9.0)
      println(far + "en farhenheit")
      far
    } else if (typeDeg == "f") {
      val celsit = (ciferTemp * (5.0 / 9.0)) + 32
      println(celsit + "en celsius")
      celsit
    } else {
      // throw an exception, maybe?
      0.0
    }
  }
```

(use `==`  not `=` for comparisons,  use `{}` around the `if-else`,return the result of the calculation from each part of the `if/else`, do something when `typeDeg` has neither expected value, move the declarations of `far`  and `celsit` inside the relevant blocks (and change them to vals))

Comment: Ok, thanks I see this is working and this is great. I had put some brackets and == signs in the beginning but I have tried out so many different versions and in the end I throw the last one out here out of despair without thinking I d get so much great help....:)

Comment: That said, I do not understand why the variables should be called to make it working...

Comment: far and celsit...and I do not understand neither why changing them to val >> Isn't it supposed to be a kind of constant?

Comment: Paul, this far and celsit lines really make me perplex...Could you enlight me a bit please?

Comment: First `val` doesn't mean constant. It means they can't be changed after initialisation. Since you don't need to re-assign them here, it's clearer to make them `val`s. Second, in Scala, an `if`/`else` is an expression and it returns the last value in the `if` or the `else` part. In this case, that needs to be the converted temperature value, either `far` or `celsit`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you started a statement with `else`.

With an `if` block, you can only omit the `{`curly brackets`}` if there is exactly one statement. Since you put a second statement, the compiler assumes that it is not part of the `if` block, and therefore the `else` that comes after is the start of a brand new expression. Since `else` isn't a valid start of an expression, the compiler is confused, and gives you that error.

Since you intend have multiple lines/statements in your initial `if` block, you should wrap it with brackets. You should also indent both of those lines (lack of proper indentation isn't the problem here, but is still important).

(oh and you are using an assignment operator `=` where you should have an equality operator `==`)

Here's what it ought to look like:

```
if(typeDeg == "c"){
  far = (ciferTemp - 32) / (5.0 / 9.0)
  println(far + "en farhenheit")
} else if(typeDeg == "f") {
  celsit = (ciferTemp * (5.0 / 9.0)) + 32
  println(celsit + "en celsius")
}
```

Comment: That still gives an error as you're returning Unit from the function

Comment: Oh, my bad; I was focused on the if/else block. Since OP appears to be a beginner, and that issue is not really what he was asking about, I'll leave that as an "exercise to the reader" rather than solving that problem.

Answer (score 2):

@Dylan addresses some issues with the `if else` and `==`. Here's how you could do it with pattern matching to make it even more concise. You can add other cases to handle conversions to other units of measure and one for invalid `typeDeg` input.

```
def TempConversion(ciferTemp: Double, typeDeg: String): Double = typeDeg match {
   case "c" => (ciferTemp - 32) / (5.0 / 9.0)
   case "f" => (ciferTemp * (5.0 / 9.0)) + 32
}
```

Comment: Loses the printlns (which then requires a val). But neater, nonetheless